# Reverse UIBezierPath for single sided corners

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I want to create a mask path whose final output will be a corner with a concave face.

I have created a `UIBezierPath` using the `-bezierPathWithRoundedRect:byRoundingCorners:cornerRadii:` method and specified that only one corner need to be rounded (*in this example, the `UIRectCornerBottomLeft`*) and I thought that by reversing this path, I should get what would have been cut in the first place.
For this, I am trying `-bezierPathByReversingPath` but it doesn't seem to make any difference (*with or without as I am getting the normal bezier path and not the reversed*)

This is what I have tried so far:

```
UIView *vwTest = [[UIView alloc] init];
[vwTest setFrame:CGRectMake(100.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f)];
[vwTest setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.view addSubview:vwTest];

UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:vwTest.bounds
                                               byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft
                                                     cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(50.0f, 50.0f)];

//get reverse path but doesn't seem to work as I think it should
maskPath = [maskPath bezierPathByReversingPath]; 

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[maskLayer setFrame:vwTest.bounds];
[maskLayer setPath:maskPath.CGPath];

[vwTest.layer setMask:maskLayer];
[vwTest.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[vwTest setNeedsDisplay];
```

---

As per the image below, what I am trying to achieve is to show the red part of the `UIView` and eliminate the rest of the area.

[image: maskPath Idea]

---

For the time being, I am doing shit like subview on subview and syncing the color of one subview with the main view's background color (*sucks but atleast I got the required output*):

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

UIView *vwTest = [[UIView alloc] init];
[vwTest setFrame:CGRectMake(100.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f)];
[vwTest setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.view addSubview:vwTest];

UIView *vwPatch = [[UIView alloc] init];
[vwPatch setFrame:vwTest.bounds];
[vwPatch setBackgroundColor:vwTest.superview.backgroundColor];
[vwTest addSubview:vwPatch];

UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:vwPatch.bounds
                                               byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft
                                                     cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(50.0f, 50.0f)];
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[maskLayer setFrame:vwPatch.bounds];
[maskLayer setPath:maskPath.CGPath];

[vwPatch.layer setMask:maskLayer];
[vwPatch.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[vwPatch setNeedsDisplay];
```

---

Someone, kindly point me in the right direction.

Comment: I think you'll need to draw the path manually, and then use [`addArcWithCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBezierPath/addArcWithCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:). Can you post a example image you want in your question - it'll help with an answer :)

Comment: i tried `-bezierPathWithArcCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:` but wasn't able to get anywhere either. Anyways... I'll post an image and add it in the question.

Comment: @Rich : ok, i added an image... now, i will look into your answer on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From looking at the code in the question I've assumed you wanted the bottom left corner (as you are using `UIRectCornerBottomLeft`) be concave with a radius of 30. You can't use [`bezierPathByReversingPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBezierPath/bezierPathByReversingPath) as all is does it literally reverse the path, it also says in the docs:

> Reversing a path does not necessarily change the appearance of the path when rendered.

**EDIT:**
Now that an image has been added to the question, the OP wants the inverse of the shape:

```
CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];
mask.frame = view.layer.bounds;

UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
CGFloat radius = 50;
CGRect rect = mask.bounds;
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect))];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect) - radius)];
[path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(rect) + radius, CGRectGetMaxY(rect) - radius) radius:radius startAngle:M_PI endAngle:M_PI_2 clockwise:NO];
[path closePath];

mask.path = path.CGPath;
view.layer.mask = mask;
```

The shape of the path is then red bit from the OPs image in the question.

---

**Answer before image was posted - might be used for others**

The following code will produce this shape:

[image: shape]

```
CGFloat cornerRadius = 30;

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100);

UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

// Draw the complete sides
[path moveToPoint:rect.origin];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect))];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect))];

// Stop short for the start of the arc
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(rect) + cornerRadius, CGRectGetMaxY(rect))];

// Concave arc
[path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect)) radius:cornerRadius startAngle:0 endAngle:M_PI_2 * 3 clockwise:NO];

// Complete the path
[path closePath];
```

### Update: Useful category

Category on `UIBezierPath` so you can pick which corners (bit mask of `UIRectCorner`s) and a radius.

**UIBezierPath+RDHConcaveCorners.h**

```
@interface UIBezierPath (RDHConcaveCorners)

+(instancetype)bezierPathWithRoundedRect:(CGRect)rect byConcaveRoundingCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners cornerRadius:(CGFloat)radius;

@end
```

**UIBezierPath+RDHConcaveCorners.m**

```
@implementation UIBezierPath (RDHConcaveCorners)

+(instancetype)bezierPathWithRoundedRect:(CGRect)rect byConcaveRoundingCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners cornerRadius:(CGFloat)cornerRadius
{
    CGFloat halfWidth = CGRectGetWidth(rect) / 2;
    CGFloat halfHeight = CGRectGetHeight(rect) / 2;
    if (cornerRadius > halfWidth || cornerRadius > halfHeight) {
        cornerRadius = MIN(halfWidth, halfHeight);
    }

    UIBezierPath *path = [self bezierPath];

    CGPoint topLeft = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    if (corners & UIRectCornerTopLeft) {
        [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(topLeft.x, topLeft.y + cornerRadius)];
        [path addArcWithCenter:topLeft radius:cornerRadius startAngle:M_PI_2 endAngle:0 clockwise:NO];
    } else {
        [path moveToPoint:topLeft];
    }

    CGPoint topRight = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    if (corners & UIRectCornerTopRight) {
        [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(topRight.x - cornerRadius, topRight.y)];
        [path addArcWithCenter:topRight radius:cornerRadius startAngle:M_PI endAngle:M_PI_2 clockwise:NO];
    } else {
        [path addLineToPoint:topRight];
    }

    CGPoint bottomRight = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));
    if (corners & UIRectCornerBottomRight) {
        [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(bottomRight.x, bottomRight.y - cornerRadius)];
        [path addArcWithCenter:bottomRight radius:cornerRadius startAngle:M_PI_2 * 3 endAngle:M_PI clockwise:NO];

    } else {
        [path addLineToPoint:bottomRight];
    }

    CGPoint bottomLeft = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));
    if (corners & UIRectCornerBottomLeft) {
        [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(bottomLeft.x + cornerRadius, bottomLeft.y)];
        [path addArcWithCenter:bottomLeft radius:cornerRadius startAngle:0 endAngle:M_PI_2 * 3 clockwise:NO];
    } else {
        [path addLineToPoint:bottomLeft];
    }

    // Complete the path
    [path closePath];

    return path;
}

@end
```

Comment: Updated with code for a useful category on `UIBezierPath` for selecting individual corners (or all of them)!

Comment: @staticVoidMan Now that you've added an image, I now see what you wanted to do by reserving the path - you wanted the inverse of it. I've updated my answer with a more useful solution that I originally provided!

Comment: @Rich : awesome. the first code example is exactly what I want. I was hoping `-bezierPathByReversingPath` to do this in one step but thanks for the bezier path data and kudos for the category as well. thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Rich hey man, can you help? I want to use your code on swift, I have created the bridge for objective c code, but I don't know how I should use the code on swift